# What is "upside down" and "inside out" in Esperanto?

Tags: single-word-requests, prepositions, adjectives

How can I say "upside down" and "inside out"?

I find it difficult to translate them – I don't know which grammar constriction I should use. Most often the expressions describes a state, right? Should I then use an adjective-ending?

It's upside down - Gxi estas supraflanksuba

That looks odd, but I can not think of a better adjective.

Maybe "Gxi havas la supron suben" is a better way to think of it.

Answer (score 11):

”upside down” could be translated as **renversita**. [PIV](http://vortaro.net/#renversi) gives some examples, such as: *li renversis la vinbotelon, por ĝui ĝis la lasta guto* ”he turned the wine bottle upside-down in order to enjoy even the last drop”.

I’m not sure about ”inside out”, though. I guess it could be **reversita** – PIV mentions ”reversi” in the context of [re-sewing](http://vortaro.net/#reverso) clothes with the inside out.

BTW, it would be fun to see Diana Ross’ song [”Upside down”](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F1ehMxQdCtQ) in Esperanto… :-)

Answer (score 8):

I have trouble with this too, not because of confusion over what part of speech to use, but because Esperanto seems to have a few words with similar meanings - and it seems to divide the semantic space differently from how English does.

- *Inversa* means to be in the opposite position or direction.
- *Renversita* means turned upside-down or knocked over.
- *La fundon supren* is one suggestion from Wells for upside down. I've also said *kapon malsupren*. Benson has *kun la kapo malsupra.*

Similarly

- *Reversi* means to turn a garment inside out and then sew it to make it look like it was meant to be that way.
- *Interno-ekstere* or *interno-ekstera* is Benson's suggestion for inside out.